# Are there any modern alarm clock software titles for 10.8?

Tags: software-recommendation

I used to use Hanson's "Alarm Clock 2", and while it was good in that I could set alarms to only go off Monday through Friday, it wasn't very good about honoring 3 day weekends.

I was hoping to find something I could just point at an .ical or Google calendar of the company holidays, so that the alarm clock would not trigger on those days.

Does anything like this exist for OS X?

Comment: It would be easier to propose a solution if you described the real-world problem you are trying to solve. Do you want to link the alarm clock to a calendar to be awakens only on work days?

Comment: @patrix Yes, and I thought that was clear.